# How to use PHP echo string in .blade.php file Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to use the `<?php echo` command in welcome.blade.php but do not know the right syntax

Tried all the workarounds but nothing

```
<div class="col">
@php
$decoded_json =json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"),     TRUE);
function price($curr) {
    global $decoded_json;
    $js = array_column($decoded_json, 'price_usd', 'id');
    return $js[$curr];
}
@endphp

<body>
BTC $<?php echo price("bitcoin");?>
<br />
 LTC $<?php echo price("litecoin"); ?>.
<br />
XMR $<?php echo price("monero"); ?>.
</body>
```

The code in between @php & @endphp works fine but when i add `<?php echo string throw a 500 error`

Edit: I now have

```
<center><h2>BTC $<?php= price("bitcoin");?></h2></center>
<center><h2>LTC $<?php= price("litecoin");?></h2></center>
<center><h2>XMR $<?php= price("monero");?></h2></center>
```

Page loads, but no values load. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hope you’re aware that half of this doesn’t belong into the template in the first place.

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to figure out how to use a route/controller with no luck 

Tried to follow this and few other things on github and got lost

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/588/how-to-retrieve-information-and-the-value-of-any-cryptocurrency-bitcoin-ethereum-in-laravel


This is as far as i come and atleast got this working just need to get the echo commands to work

Comment: `<?php= ` is not valid syntax, it’s either just `<?=`, or you need to explicitly indicate that you want to create output when using the normal tags, `<?php`, by following that with `echo`/`print` first.

Comment: When i remove php out of <?php= to <?= i get a error

Comment: Only vaguely mentioning that you “get errors”, without telling us what those actually are, is quite pointless.

Comment: "array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given (View: /var/www/website/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)"
-------------------------------------------

<?php
$decoded_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"),     TRUE);
function price($curr) {
global $decoded_json;
$js = array_column($decoded_json, 'price_usd', 'id');
    return $js[$curr];
}
 
 
 
?>
</hr> 
<br />
<center><h2>BTC $<?= price("bitcoin");?> | LTC $<?= price("litecoin");?> | XMR $<?= price("monero");?></h2></center>
 
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: That is an error coming from your `price` function - apparently `$decoded_json` is not what you expected it to be, but simply NULL. You can check `json_last_error`/`json_last_error_msg` to find out what went wrong when attempting to decode the JSON. (Most likely perhaps though that trying to fetch the data using file_get_contents returned either an error message instead of the expected JSON, or just an empty string because something failed on the network level.)

Answer (score 0):

You really are fighting against the framework by doing everything in the view. Might as well just use plain-old-php if you're going to do it that way.

Nevertheless, if you really don't want to use a controller, you can keep the logic somewhat separated by performing the API lookup in your routes file `web.php` and then pass the data to the view.

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"),true);
    $currencyValues = array_column($response, 'price_usd', 'id');

    // Now call your view and pass in the data so the view has access to it. 
    // Notice that the view will have access to a variable named `$currencies` and not `$currencyValues` 
    return view('welcome', [
        'currencies' => $currencyValues
    ]);
});
```

And then, in your your view, `welcome.blade.php`, you can output the currencies that were retrieved.

*Edit - Forgot we were working in Blade. Added `{{ ... }}`.*

```
{{ $currencies['bitcoin'] }}

<br />

{{ $currencies['litecoin'] }}
```

Comment: So just want to be sure im doing this right the first part i should put at the end of my web.php in routes folder and the second part i put in welcome.blade.php where i want it shown?

Comment: Undefined variable: currencies (View: /var/www/website/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)

Comment: Right. But you need to replace your `Route::get('/', function () { ... }` with the one I wrote. Don't just paste it at the end of your file. You should only have 1 definition for `Route::get('/', ...)`. These routes are fundamental to Laravel (and most web frameworks) so I suggest reading about them.

Comment: Route::name('auth.')->group(function () {
    include 'auth.php';
});
Route::prefix('admin') -> group(function (){
    Route::middleware(['admin_panel_access'])->group(function () {
        include 'admin.php';
    });
}); 


// Profile routes
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('banned', 'ProfileController@banned')->name('profile.banned');
    Route::middleware(['is_banned']) -> group(function(){
        include 'profile.php';
    });
})
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@home')->name('home');

Comment: Seems i have a Route::get('/', 'IndexController@home')->name('home'); in my web.php that works with my script is there a work around. Or could you tell me how to set up a controller and connect it?